# proper JSON format: newline not allowed for each item in a JSON array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string, file

I want to use JS to read from an external JSON file, which is an array of n objects, and n is big. So, preferably, I want to write the array with each object taking a line. However, I found it only worked when everything is put in one single line; any line break messed things up. I wonder why. Below, I use a simplified example to illustrate. Odd!

The `data.json` file that worked:

```
data = '[{"name": "Ashwin","age": "20"},{"name": "Abhinandan","age": "21"}]';
```

The `data.json` file that did not work:

```
data = '[{"name": "Ashwin","age": "20"},
         {"name": "Abhinandan","age": "21"}]';
```

The HTML file with JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script>
<script>
var mydata = JSON.parse(data);
alert(mydata[0].name);
alert(mydata[0].age);
alert(mydata[1].name);
alert(mydata[1].age);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use newline characters in JS string literals without escaping them using the backslash character. You can use newline characters without escaping them in JS string templates though. Both examples shown in the snippet below:

```js
let data = '[{"name": "Ashwin","age": "20"},\
         {"name": "Abhinandan","age": "21"}]';
         
console.log(JSON.parse(data));

data = `[{"name": "Ashwin","age": "20"},
         {"name": "Abhinandan","age": "21"}]`;
         
console.log(JSON.parse(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is an invalid JSON file. Instead you have a js file. There are two ways to solve this:

1. Use a proper JSON file:

   data.json:

   ```
   [
       {"name": "Ashwin","age": "20"},
       {"name": "Abhinandan","age": "21"}
   ]
   ```

   html:

   ```
   <script>
   fetch('data.json').then(function(result){
       var mydata = JSON.parse(result);
       alert(mydata[0].name);
       alert(mydata[0].age);
       alert(mydata[1].name);
       alert(mydata[1].age);
   });
   </script>
   ```
2. Or simply use javascript to pass the data

   data.js:

   ```
   // Notice that the code below is not JSON,
   // it is a regular javascript array assigned
   // to a global variable (no "var"):
   data = [
       {"name": "Ashwin","age": "20"},
       {"name": "Abhinandan","age": "21"}
   ];

   // Notice also that unlike JSON, this file
   // can contain comments and other code!
   ```

   html:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="data.js"></script>
   <script>
   // Notice that since you've imported an array and not
   // a JSON data you don't need to JSON.parse:
   alert(data[0].name);
   alert(data[0].age);
   alert(data[1].name);
   alert(data[1].age);
   </script>
   ```

Comment: thanks! can i ask a follow-up question: what's the requirement for json format? and what's that for js format?

Comment: JSON is a text data format (like XML or CSV) invented by Douglas Crockford as a subset of javascript object literal format. The specification for JSON can be found here: http://json.org/. Basically, it is the same as object literal except keys must always be quoted, string quotes must always be double quotes ("), and some value types or syntax are illegal (functions, variables, hexadecimal or octal number formats etc.)

Comment: The reason he removed a lot of features of object literal syntax form JSON is to make JSON easy to parse in languages like C. JSON is supposed to be a data exchange format after all and being easy to parse would make it more likely to be successful